# Photo taken using an app created in andorid appears blurred while saving

Tags: android

I wanted to develop an android app using which I take a photo and add geocordinates, location name and bearing to it. Though the app was developed while saving phtoto the photo seems to be blurred. I tested the app in 1 plus 6 mobile phone. What could be the reason?

Comment: Do share the code you are using to save the file.

Comment: Most likely, you used the thumbnail image and not the full size photo.

Comment: How can I save full size photo instead of thumbnail image? Tried different codes but not able to get it right.